# Filter list results with <select/> drop-down list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to filter a 'Project Index' by tags using jQuery and CSS.

I am currently taking the `.val()` of the selected option in a `<select>` dropdown list and checking if it's equal to the inner `.html()` of a `.tag`. If they match it will make the project entry black, if else it will make it light gray.

My current code works when the project has one tag, but once there are multiple tags it breaks. My guess is that because although there is one `.tag` equal to the selected dropdown value, the other `.tag` are not,  therefore using the `else` condition?

What am I missing? Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

HTML

```
<main>
  <div class="index__container">
     <section class="index">
        <ul class="index__header">
            <li>Project</li>
            <li>Filter: <select id="index__filter">
                <option selected="selected" value='ALL'>All</option>
                <option value="Pedagogical Explorations">Pedagogical Explorations</option>
                <option value="Research Production">Research Production</option>
                <option value="Spatial Practice">Spatial Practice</option>
                <option value="Exhibition">Exhibition</option>
            </select></li>
            <li>Year</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Multiscale Strategies to Reactivate Transhumance in Spain</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Architecture after Speculation</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Polyester Merino Chair</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>1500 caracteres</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                    <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Europan 13: Die Arbeitersiedlung</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                </li>
                <li>2015</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Asymmetric Meta-Mapping</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Pedagogical Explorations</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
             </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Chicago Architecture Biennial</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                    <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
                    <span class="tag">Exhibition</span></li>
                <li>2015</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

JS

```
  // Filter Project Index
  var $indexSelect = $('#index__filter');
  var $indexEntry = $('.index__entry');
  var $tag = $('.tag');

  $indexSelect.change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue == 'ALL'){
       $indexEntry.css('color', 'black');
     return;
    }

    $tag.each(function(i,option){
     if ($(this).html() == selectedValue) {
        $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'black');
        console.log($(this).text());
      } else {
       $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'lightgray');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: It is working as you have implemented it. According to your condition it is making the matched tag *black* and unmatched ones as *gray*. If you want any other result please explain that requirement in detail.

Comment: any example if there are multiple tags and it breaks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working code for you. What you are doing is exactly right, except that you need to assign a class to the `ul` and have a check for that too. Try the below code:

```js
var $indexSelect = $('#index__filter');
var $indexEntry = $('.index__entry');
var $tag = $('.tag');

$indexSelect.change(function() {
  $indexEntry.removeClass('selected');
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  if (selectedValue == 'ALL') {
    $indexEntry.css('color', 'black');
    return;
  }

  $tag.each(function(i, option) {
    if (!$(this).closest('ul').hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'lightgray');
      if ($(this).html() == selectedValue) {
        $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'black').addClass('selected');
        //console.log($(this).text());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="index__container">
    <section class="index">
      <ul class="index__header">
        <li>Project</li>
        <li>Filter: <select id="index__filter">
                <option selected="selected" value='ALL'>All</option>
                <option value="Pedagogical Explorations">Pedagogical Explorations</option>
                <option value="Research Production">Research Production</option>
                <option value="Spatial Practice">Spatial Practice</option>
                <option value="Exhibition">Exhibition</option>
            </select></li>
        <li>Year</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>Multiscale Strategies to Reactivate Transhumance in Spain</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
          </li>
          <li>2017</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>Architecture after Speculation</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
          </li>
          <li>2017</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>Polyester Merino Chair</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
          </li>
          <li>2017</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>1500 caracteres</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
            <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
          </li>
          <li>2017</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>Europan 13: Die Arbeitersiedlung</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
          </li>
          <li>2015</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>Asymmetric Meta-Mapping</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Pedagogical Explorations</span>
          </li>
          <li>2017</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <ul class="index__entry">
          <li>Chicago Architecture Biennial</li>
          <li>
            <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
            <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
            <span class="tag">Exhibition</span></li>
          <li>2015</li>
        </ul>
      </a>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Milan!! I didnt know you were able to have nested `if ()` statements. Working perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $indexSelect = $('#index__filter');
var $indexEntry = $('.index__entry');


$indexSelect.change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if (selectedValue == 'ALL') {
        $indexEntry.css('color', 'black');
        return;
    }

    $indexEntry.each(function(i, option) {
        debugger;
        var $tag = $(this).find('.tag');
        var flag = true;
        $tag.each(function(i, option) {
            if (flag == true) {
                if ($(this).html() == selectedValue) {
                    $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'black');
                    console.log($(this).text());
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'lightgray');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looping trough all the tags, and aply styling for each tag it will only show the styling for the last tag of each entry.

If you loop per entry, and than per tag in each entry you can break out of the loop once you have found a tag that matches the selected tag.

```
// loop trough each entry
$indexEntry.each(function(i,entry){
  // loop trough tag iwithin the entry
  $( this ).find( '.tag' ).each(function(i, tag){
    if ($(this).html() == selectedValue) {
        $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'black');
        // exit this loop as soon as we've determined it should be black
        return false; 
    } else {
       $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'lightgray');
    }
  })
})
```

```js
$(function(){
// Filter Project Index
  var $indexSelect = $('#index__filter');
  var $indexEntry = $('.index__entry');
  var $tag = $('.tag');

  $indexSelect.change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue == 'ALL'){
       $indexEntry.css('color', 'black');
     return;
    }

    $indexEntry.each(function(i,entry){
      $( this ).find( '.tag' ).each(function(i, tag){
        if ($(this).html() == selectedValue) {
            $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'black');
            return false;
            console.log($(this).text());
          } else {
           $(this).closest('ul').css('color', 'lightgray');
          }
      })
    })

    
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="index__container">
     <section class="index">
        <ul class="index__header">
            <li>Project</li>
            <li>Filter: <select id="index__filter">
                <option selected="selected" value='ALL'>All</option>
                <option value="Pedagogical Explorations">Pedagogical Explorations</option>
                <option value="Research Production">Research Production</option>
                <option value="Spatial Practice">Spatial Practice</option>
                <option value="Exhibition">Exhibition</option>
            </select></li>
            <li>Year</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Multiscale Strategies to Reactivate Transhumance in Spain</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Architecture after Speculation</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Polyester Merino Chair</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>1500 caracteres</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                    <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Europan 13: Die Arbeitersiedlung</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                </li>
                <li>2015</li>
            </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Asymmetric Meta-Mapping</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Pedagogical Explorations</span>
                </li>
                <li>2017</li>
             </ul>
        </a> 
        <a href="">
            <ul class="index__entry">
                <li>Chicago Architecture Biennial</li>
                <li>
                    <span class="tag">Spatial Practice</span>
                    <span class="tag">Research Production</span>
                    <span class="tag">Exhibition</span></li>
                <li>2015</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jasper. Your code makes sense, I knew I was somehow breaking the loop... works fine now. Thank you

Comment: No problem. The thing actually is that you weren't breaking the loop. And because of that once you set an entry to black, the next iteration of your loop could set it back to gray again. 
If an answer solved your problem (doesn't have to be mine, just the answer that answers your question best) , make sure to mark it as "accepted answer". That way you help other people find relevant answers to their questions.